# Does the sum exist in the given list

Tags: python, list, sum, runtime-error, sublist

I've been given a list and an integer. And I have to check whether there exist elements which can be summed up to be equal to the given integer.
Here is my code which is giving me a runtime error:

```
from itertools import combinations
def sum_checker(list, n):
    for i in range(1,len(list)+1):
        for s in combinations(list, i):
            if n == reduce(lambda a, b: a  + b, s): return True
```

Any efficient idea would be appreciable!

Comment: this sounds like a uni/school question.......

Comment: May be, This gives a runtime_error, and I think this is what makes it interesting!

Comment: Ignoring your error, your solution is really slow and inefficient. Try to be creative in how you design it.

Comment: May be, you better know!

Comment: and how am i supposed to do so?

Comment: google `dynamic programming`

Comment: Ok, that seems pretty nice, I'll do check!

Comment: Btw, `sum()` is 5-10 times faster than `reduce`.

Comment: timing is not that what matters here, runtime --> i think memory error matters here, doesn't it?